# How can I change my profile photo?

Tags: discussion

How can I change my profile photo on Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: @Takkat AskUbuntu (directly below where you type your comment) says "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post".  So, to "point out a problem IN your post", your comment is clearly not asking for clarification, and miscategorization isn't exactly a "problem in the post" is it?  I see no grammar issues, spelling is spot on, and the question itself is very concise and clear.  clicking your link blindly takes me to a 404 page, so i can't even investigate why this question "should be asked in (Meta) .... ".  I'm sorry, but your comment is utterly not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your profile page (You can access it by clicking your name at the top of the screen) click the edit link to edit your profile, then select change picture

Comment: I did all that.  Problem is, I get back "Request returned an error: [error] | Close".   Try finding a solution on google for that!  :p  I tried, for a while.  I keep getting hits on how to change my dang windows wallpaper, or my microsoft account profile picture, or whatever.  I guess i don't know how to speak google-ese

Answer (score 3):

Reuben is completely right, however alternatively just go to [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com) - this is where Ask Ubuntu gets your profile picture from (it is based on your email address).

Comment: I gotta create an account at another site to get my picture on this site to change?  That's a problem, because, i don't wanna make an account at some other site.  I'm here...not there.

Answer (score 2):

Your profile photo is based on your email address and is pulled from the free Profile Hosting site [Gravatar](http://gravatar.com/) If you don't already have an account there, sign up with the email address used on Ask Ubuntu (You can add multiple email addresses, and have multiple "profile images" setup). Upload the profile image you'd like to use for Ask Ubuntu then wait an hour or two for the cache to update.